# Are there some packages I need to install to run apps compiled with mono C#?

Tags: mono, monodevelop, c#, software-installation

I use MonoDevelop for writing and compiling C# code. I am wondering if there are some prerequisite packages to run built applications?

Also, output is always `*.exe`. Does it need to be like that and can I remove .exe?

Answer (score 0):

Mono programs require the Mono runtime, which is provided by the `mono-runtime` package. Like other programs, they may also use shared libraries provided by other packages.

MonoDevelop is itself a program written in C# that uses Mono. Any Ubuntu system with the `monodevelop` package installed will also have `mono-runtime` and some other support packages installed. This happens automatically when you install `monodevelop` using Ubuntu's package manager, because it declares the other packages it needs as dependencies.

So you likely don't need to install anything else just to run programs that use Mono. If you're developing Mono applications, though, then I suggest installing the `mono-complete` package, which will give you most of the development tools you're likely to want to use.

If you want to install less than what `mono-complete` gives you, then you can just install `mono-devel`. If you want to install less than that, and just get the C# compiler and the libraries it requires, then you can install `mono-mcs`. The C# compiler is called `mcs`; if you want to run it directly from the command line, you would use the `mcs` command.

It sounds, from your question, that you already have these things installed.

---

As for the `.exe` suffix that the C# compiler automatically appends to the binaries it produces: yes, you can remove that and they will still run just fine. You might not always want to, though. Having `.exe` at the end isn't necessary, but it doesn't do any harm. It makes your programs more readily portable to other systems, which you may or may not care about, depending on what you are doing.

In particular, if you copy those executables to a Windows system, they will probably still run, but if you've removed the `.exe` suffix, then Windows won't know what to do with them. This is because Windows uses file extensions to determine if a file is considered a program. (Of course, you could rename them back.)